# Permission Design - Allow/Deny vs Allow Only

Tags: design-patterns, permissions

I've come onto a new a project and the permissions are done with an allow and a deny option for every permission. Until now i've only ever seen/build allow only permissions.

What is the advantage of this? It seems to introduce extra complexity for developer as well as enduser.

The only situation i could think of that an Allow/Deny design can handle, that a Allow-Only can not is the following.

Role has a permission: AllowX = true and DenyX = false.
User has an empty permission.

In an allow-Only design you cannot add an empty permission to the user as only AllowX exists, so the "empty"  user scoped permission (where it says AllowX = false) would override the role scoped permission.

But there are obviously many ways to handle this. Just dont add an empty user permission by default. Make the default user permission an aggregate of the role permissions.

However you see this Allow/Deny model in windows and probably a lot bigger apps. Whats the reason?

Answer (score 5):

If you only ever deal with individual users, individual assets and individual permissions, you probably don't need a deny permission.

As soon as you deal with groups, of users, assets or permissions, deny permissions make things much easier to manage. Some slightly made up examples:

```
Allow (Users = *, Table = *, Permission = Read)
Deny (Users = *, Table = credit_card_numbers, Permission = Read)
```

or

```
Allow (Users = TeamA_Group, Table = teama_*, Permission = Write)
Deny (Users = TeamAProjectManager, Table = teama_*, Permission = Write)
```

or

```
Allow (Users = TeamA_Group, Table = teama_*, Permission = *)
Deny (Users = TeamA_Group, Table = teama_*, Permission = Delete)
```

without a deny permission in those cases, you'd have to individually give read permission on every other table, to each member of TeamA other than the project manager, or to every non-delete permission. That's both error prone and needs action every time a new table / team member / permission arrives as opposed to just doing the right thing by default.

Answer (score 1):

Allow/Deny allows hierarchical permissions, commonly demonstrated by files and folders.

ie  UserA can read and write the contents of /folder but is denied write for folder/file1

In this way, where there are many files in the folder I can express the permissions more succinctly than an Allow for every file plus a deny of the file1.

However! It's a flawed system. As the number of groups and objects increase the overlapping permissions become impossible to manage. In order to work out whether a user has a permission or not you have to calculate the combination of groups. No problem for a computer, but difficult for a human.

You can achieve the same complexity with a single layer permission system and "Roles". Each role gets a combination of single layer permissions, which don't change  and users are assigned to roles.

Because the permissions are static and require no calculation they are easily understood, and because users are assigned to these roles rather than each having their own combination of permissions you can easily state who can do what.

Comment: What's the difference between a role and a group?

Comment: A role is a set of permissions and a group is a set of users. so i might say everyone in the group "AuditorTeamNewYork" is in the Role "Auditor" which has permissions "Read Audit"

Comment: I still don't get the purpose behind the distinction. Why have a distinct role concept rather than just giving the "AuditorTeamNewYork" group the "Read Audit" permission? Alternatively why have a distinct group concept when you could just assign people the "Auditor" role? I can understand not directly managing every permission on every person, but why do you need two layers of indirection?

Comment: a role is essentially a group of permissions. so you can assign more than one role to a group or person, but still keep the sets of permissions distinct. If you assign the audit permissions to AuditorTeam directly, and then some ReadReports permissions and Then the team lead gets ApproveTimesheet permissions everyone ends up with a whole bunch of random permissions and its hard to ever remove them, or work out why person X has them

Comment: Why would the team lead be getting directly assigned permissions? They would be added to the TeamLead group which would have the ApproveTimesheet permission.

Comment: well then you have just renamed groups to roles, but your missing the "everyone in team X is an auditor" layer. traditionally you had users, groups and permissions, the alternate is users, groups, roles and permissions and often we just lose the permissions because the role is enough

Comment: Okay so we have roles, which are often called groups on many platforms. Then what is *your* definition of groups and what purpose do they serve that isn't already served by roles?

Comment: ok. one more time. groups are not roles. a group is a set of users, a role is a set of permissions. you need both. If you dont have roles you get the problem outlined in the comment above. if you don't have groups then you cant sub divide the users into smaller sets, "the new york office" etc which is normally considered a key part of user profiles, although distinct from "roles"

Comment: The assertion that roles don't subdivide users doesn't make sense: By assigning the "Supervisor" role to some users, you are creating the subset of users with the "Supervisor" role (and, implicitly, its inverse).